# CSS - Custom select text-overflow

Tags: firefox, select, ellipsis, css

I wanted to make a custom select in HTML with CSS **only**. So I did the trick with the  around the select in order to have a custom arrow ([View here](http://goo.gl/uM9Rbe)).

I want to set the text-overflow of the select to 'ellipsis'. But now long options overlap my custom-arrow. Is there a way **to limit the max. text-width** of a select, so that the ellipsis would be before my custom arrow?

PS: I am using Firefox and I only want to use CSS for this. So please no solutions in JS.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you didn't do that.. I had read the same in a blog.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to style a <select> dropdown with CSS only without JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```
.truncate {    
    max-width: TRUNCATION-BOUNDARY;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jtxGb)

So in your case just set `max-width` to something like 90% (or even less), so it doesn't overlap you arrow anymore.